# Are positively biased bootstrap-derived GAM predictions indicative of model issues?

Tags: r, predictive-models, modeling, bootstrap, generalized-additive-model

all,

I am using a negative binomial GAM fitted with mgcv::gam to estimate counts for new data, and I wanted to use bootstrapping to find a 95% confidence interval for point estimates. In my bootstrapping function, I resample from original data, refit the model and run that refit model on the data for which I want count estimates. I believe this is called a nonparametric bootstrap. It is my understanding that the mean of the bootstrapped model predictions should equal the mean of my model predictions when applied to the original data. This small simulation, that I ran in R, seems to confirm that:

```
> x <- rnbinom(1000, 1, 0.002)
> b <- replicate(10000, mean(x[sample.int(1000, replace=T)]))
> c(sample.mean = mean(x), bootstrap.mean = mean(b))
   sample.mean bootstrap.mean 
       507.376        507.405
```

When applied to my GAM, however, my bootstrapped estimates are on average about 5% greater than estimates that stem from the original data, and I wonder if this is cause for concern. I've tried to illustrate these results in the figure below. The left panel shows a histogram of my 1000 bootstrap estimates. The red and blue lines represent my estimate from original data and the mean of my bootstrap estimates, respectively. The right panel shows the mean of the all bootstrap estimates up to the ith bootstrap iteration, so at e.g. x = 100, the y-value corresponds to the mean of the first 100 bootstrap estimates. The light blue region similarly represents the 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles of the bootstrap estimates up to the ith estimate.

[image: Left: histogram showing frequency and range of bootstrapped estimates. Right: Mean of bootstrap bootstrap estimates up to the ith bootstrap iteration]

*Figure: Left: histogram showing frequency and range of bootstrapped estimates. Right: Mean of bootstrap bootstrap estimates up to the ith bootstrap iteration*

**Based on these results, I have two questions:**

1. Could these results be indicative of a serious problem with my model?
2. If these results are not symptomatic of a serious problem, should I correct my point estimate (derived from the model fitted on the original data) by subtracting the bias?

This is my first time posting on stackexchange - I searched thoroughly among already answered questions before posting this, but couldn't really find any answers that I could wrap my head around. Thank you for any pointers you may provide!

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. Can you please provided a minimum reproducible example? 2. "*It is my understanding that the mean of the bootstrapped model predictions should equal the mean of my model predictions when applied to the original data.*" unfortunately that is not always the case especially for statistics that are not linear functions of the data. i.e. this holds for an OLS (as shown in that R 3-liner) but not for NB. 3. On face value what you report appears reasonable. You might want to explore "bias-corrected (and accelerated bootstrap" too.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the response! Unfortunately, the model in question is fairly complicated and I don't know how I'd share a reproducible example without giving away confidential data. I realize seeing the model formula and knowing more about the data used to fit it might be critical to assessing the problem (if indeed there is one), but I was hoping something could be gleaned from my results, on a conceptual level, I guess.

Comment: No problem, I can appreciate that, maybe you can simulate a simpler dataset? Can you also please clarify: what exactly do you mean by "*counts for new data*"? Do you sum up all the new estimates? Just to show what I mean by my point 2: `set.seed(1); N=1e4; A=MASS::rnegbin(n=N, mu=10, theta=3);B=replicate(N, expm1(mean(log1p(sample(A, replace=TRUE))))); mean(A)-mean(B)`.

Comment: That's very interesting, thank you. It seems your code demonstrates that in some cases bootstrapping can lead to negatively biased estimates. So in and of itself, bias in bootstrap estimates might not necessarily spell out doom for my model. This makes me even more uncertain as to whether to subtract my bootstrap bias from my original data point estimate. To answer your question: yes, in each bootstrap replication, I return the sum of all predicted responses, as in `sum(predict(mod, newdata, type="response"))`.

Comment: Bootstrapping (non-parametric) data and fitting your GAM to the resamples is known to undersmooth because of the duplicated observations. That undersmoothing is a source of bias in the models fitted to bootstrap samples.

Comment: I see, @ReinstateMonica-G.Simpson, thanks for pointing that out. So in a sense, it is not at all unexpected that bootstrapping GAMs with multiple smooths would lead to biased estimates. Would you agree then, that in my case, I probably should 1) not bias-correct my point estimates from the model fitted on the original data, but 2) use a bias-corrected confidence interval like BCa?

Comment: I'm still not clear what you want to do? Is it just to put an interval on the prediction? You don't need to do bootstrapping to do that with a GAM as you can simulate from the model's posterior distribution, and include the uncertainty due to smoothness selection